# How disable the module related to path Enterprise/GiftWrapping/Helper/Data.php

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, error

Recently we are getting the following warning. What is this? How to avoid it as it makes the log very big.

```
ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/GiftWrapping/Helper/Data.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in
/magento/installation/path/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the module Enterprise/GiftWrapping exit in the system at **`app/code/core`**.

I guess that

- Magento C.E - 1.9 does not contain the module Enterprise_GiftWrapping
- Maybe in your code, the module Enterprise_GiftWrapping module does not exist.
- Or Enterprise_GiftWrapping does exist, but helper class not available
- Maybe there are spell issue in the module helper class

In order to check availability. You can try

```
use Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Enterprise_GiftWrapping') for check extension
```

Comment: There's a spell on all our helper classes :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. My main issue is with finding the module. In app/code/core/Mage there are GiftMessage or GiftRegistry but no GiftWarpping!

Comment: @Zinat could you solve this error message? I'm having the same message but dont know how to fix it. I have only GiftMessage Folder under /app/code/core/Mage

Comment: @float Unfortunately not, still we are getting this error

Comment: @Zinat,what magento version,you have using

Comment: magento 1.9.1.0. Amit your points are totally correct. I found try {if (class_exists("Enterprise_GiftWrapping_Helper_Data", true)) {$this->_entGWHelper = Mage::helper('enterprise_giftwrapping');} } catch (Exception $e) {} in our 3rd party extension. Considering your first point, I don't know if removing this is safe or not?

Comment: use `Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Enterprise_GiftWrapping')` for check extension

Answer (score 2):

This happens if extensions try to find out if other extensions are active with `class_exists()`. `class_exists()` triggers the autoloader and unfortunately the Varien_Autoload implementation does not check if a class file exists but just includes the path where it assumes the class to be located. If it does not exist, this warning occurs.

**Solution: Never use `class_exists()` in Magento.**

In your case, `class_exists("Enterprise_GiftWrapping_Helper_Data")` can be replaced with `Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Enterprise_GiftWrapping')`

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem, this is caused by a Vaimo module to use klarna. They have the same code and changed this:

Old code:

```
if ($this->_entGWHelper==NULL) {
    $this->_entGWHelper = $moduleHelper; 
    try {
        if (class_exists("Enterprise_GiftWrapping_Helper_Data", true)) {
            $this->_entGWHelper = Mage::helper('enterprise_giftwrapping');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

Change this to

```
if ($this->_entGWHelper==NULL) {
    $this->_entGWHelper = $moduleHelper; 
    if ($this->_getHelper()->isEnterpriseAndHasClass('Enterprise_GiftWrapping_Helper_Data')) {
        $this->_entGWHelper = Mage::helper('enterprise_giftwrapping');
    }
}
```

The log entry will not show again.